# does below java multi-threads example always deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading

```
Object o1 = new Object();
Object o2 = new Object();
```

Thread1:

```
synchronized(o1){
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    synchronized(o2){
      //do something
    }
}
```

Thread2:

```
synchronized(o2){
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    synchronized(o1){
      //do something
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
new Thread1().start();
new Thread2().start();
```

does above code always deadlock, if not, why?

Comment: No.  Think about all the possible sequences in which the two threads can go through the synchronized blocks.

Comment: yes, i can reproduce deaclock every time, but the right answer is not, this isn't deadlock every time, i want to know the reason.

Comment: @NeilMasson could you please give sequences which not cause the deadlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because once a thread wakes up, it will not be able to enter the next synchronized section because the lock is already taken.

(There could be a **theoretical** scenario where there will not be a deadlock - if one thread gets both locks before second thread got cpu time to even get the first lock)

Comment: i also think about it like you, but the right answer is that it don't always deadlock, i just want to know what are cases it will not deadlock

Comment: yes, i think "if one thread gets both locks before second thread got cpu time to even get the first lock" is right

Comment: do you have other cases?

Comment: @CarlXu I doubt that either thread will complete before the other begins, given the `Thread.Sleep(1000)`. If you got rid of the sleep, and the synchronized work done in `do something` completed quickly, then there would be a reasonable chance of no deadlock.

Comment: @CarlXu there are no more possible cases I believe

Comment: one more question, is it possible Thread2 run first before Thread1, i remember it maybe reordering

Comment: @CarlXu - Sure, it depends on the scheduler (the entity which manages the cpu time each thread/process gets), the main thread can run, create both threads without them running yet, and then decide to give cpu to Thread2 before Thread1 (it will not always be FIFO=First In First Out)

Answer (score 1):

Call Thread1 `A` and Thread2 `B`.  `A1` means the first thread has locked on `o1` etc.  Possible sequences of operation are

```
A1:A2:B2:B1
A1:B2 - deadlock on steps A2 and B1
B2:A1 - deadlock on steps B1 and A2
B2:B1:A1:A2
```

So the code will not deadlock if one thread completes its operation before the second thread executes its first `synchronized` block.  When either thread executes is controlled by the system scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is "No."

The `sleep()` calls make it extremely likely that the two threads will deadlock, but they do not *guarantee* that the two threads will deadlock.

Your "test code" thread starts the "thread1" and "thread2" threads like so:

```
new Thread1().start();
new Thread2().start();
```

If the two threads start within one second of each other, then you'll get a deadlock.  But there's no guarantee that it will come out that way.  Here's one possible serialization:

```
test code       thread1         thread2
---------       -------         -------
new Thread1
    .start()
...             lock o1
...             sleep(1000)
new Thread2     ...
    .start()    ...             waiting to run
                lock o2         ...
                do something    block on o2
                unlock o2       ...
                unlock o1       lock o2
                                sleep(1000)
                                lock o1
                                do something
                                unlock o1
                                unlock o2
```

Why did thread2 wait so long before attempting to lock o2?   Who knows?  Maybe the system was heavily loaded with other processes.  The point is, it's very unlikely to happen in this way, but it *could* happen.  Therefore, your example is not guaranteed to *always* deadlock.